# Can't connect on RDP on Google Cloud on EU servers (US works)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have problem with connecting to server on Google Cloud, I'm using free trial and while I create server in any of three European zones I can't connect to it through RDP, in case when I create servers in US-central location everything is fine. I tried it on different computers and on every each one of them the same problem has occured. In firewall port for RDP is unlocked, I'm connecting from Poland.

Comment: Have you tried to connect from an instance in the US to another instance in Europe? It looks like there is a networking issue that prevents you from connecting to the instance. What error message do you receive?